# How do I exit Excel full screen after switching desktops using MSVDM

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-excel-2003

When I switch desktops with MSVDM (Microsoft Virtual Desktop Manager) Excel goes into some kind of full screen mode, where no tool bars or menus are visible in the Excel window. Then I can not find any way to bring the tool bars and menu back. To work around I need to save the document, exit Excel and open up the document again. 
Is there a keyboard shortcut that can bring back the 'normal' Excel view again without need to close Excel?

Comment: What does 'Windows Key + D' do for you. That's supposed to minimize all of the applications on your desktop.

Comment: 'Windows Key + D' works just fine, but it doesn't solve my Excel problem. When I bring back Excel to focus tool bars and menu is still missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sequence that brings back tool bars and menu without closing Excel.
 1. 'Windows Key + D" In the desktop where Excel is.
 2. Switch to another desktop.
 3. Switch back to desktop where Excel is.
 4. Restore the Excel window.

Yes, Excel is back to 'normal'!

Thanks johnthexiii for leading me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Just minimize the excel file using the "restore down" button (Right hand corner up side middle button). That will do.

Answer (score 0):

When I put Excel 2003 into Full screen, the Menu is still available, just the tool bars go away. Try Alt-V to see if it shows the View menu.
Excel 2007 does not show the menu-bar at all.  Double-Clicking on the Title Bar brings back the menus for me.

Comment: 'Alt-V' did not work. I also tried Double-Clicking the menu-bar, no success